# How to catch assertion(caused in C++) during runtime in python

Tags: python, c++, windows, ctypes, assertions

I want to embed C++ in python application. I don't want to use Boost library.

If C++ function do assertion, I want to catch it and print error in my python application or get some detailed information like line number in python script that caused error. and main thing is "I want to proceed further in python execution flow"

How can I do it? I can't find any functions to get detailed assertion information in Python API or C++.

**C++ Code**

```
void sum(int iA, int iB)
{
    assert(iA + iB >10);
}
```

**Python Code**

```
from ctypes import * 

mydll = WinDLL("C:\\Users\\cppwrapper.dll")

try:
    mydll.sum(10,3)
catch:
print "exception occurred"

# control should  go to user whether exceptions occurs, after exception occurs if he provide yes then continue with below or else abort execution, I need help in this part as well

import re
for test_string in ['555-1212', 'ILL-EGAL']:
    if re.match(r'^\d{3}-\d{4}$', test_string):
        print test_string, 'is a valid US local phone number'
    else:
        print test_string, 'rejected'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assertion is not an exception. Therefore it can't be caught, neither in python, nor in C++.

Comment: `assert` calls `abort`, so ultimately you can't prevent killing the process. But you can use ctypes to install a callback function as a `SIGABRT` handler (Python's own signal system won't work since it's asynchronous). For Microsoft's CRT, you can also call `_set_abort_behavior` to disable error reporting. In the `SIGABRT` handler you can bring up a debug console like this: `local = sys._getframe(1).f_locals;` `code.interact('Debug Console', local=local)`.

Comment: Python's signal handler won't work. It's implemented by setting a flag for the interpreter and returning, so the process will be killed long before the handler runs. You need to use a ctypes callback instead. To create the callback just decorate a function definition with `@CFUNCTYPE(None, c_int)`. The callback is installed by calling `CDLL(None).signal(SIGABRT, callback)` in a POSIX system such as Linux. In Windows use `CDLL(ctypes.util.find_library('c'))` instead of `CDLL(None)`, except in Python 3.5+ use `CDLL('ucrtbase')`.

Comment: @eryksun I am using python python 2.7.10 , I cant switch to 3.5+ and It would be highly appreciated if you provide code examples. I'm really new to OS concepts.

Answer (score 0):

This can't really be done in exactly the way you say, (as was also pointed out in the comments).

Once the assertion happens and SIGABRT is sent to the process, it's in the operating system's hands what will happen, and generally the process will be killed.

The simplest way to recover from a process being killed, is to have the process launched by an external process. Like, a secondary python script, or a shell script. It's easy in bash scripting, for instance, to launch another process, check if it terminates normally or is aborted, log it, and continue.

For instance here's some bash code that executes command line `$command`, logs the standard error channel to a log file, checks the return code (which will be 130 or something for an SIGABRT) and does something in the various cases:

```
  $command 2> error.log
  error_code="$?"
  if check_errs $error_code; then
    # Do something...
    return 0
  else
    # Do something else...
    return 1
  fi
```

Where check_errs is some other subroutine that you would write.

Comment: Yes, but the process isn't killed until after the `SIGABRT` handler returns. So in Python you can use a ctypes callback handler to do debugging, or whatever logging/cleanup you need to do. In this case a watchdog process isn't required.

Comment: Yeah but if he wants to, continue executing normally after that, he probably wants a watchdog. I mean presumably this is like some unit test system he is making or something. > and main thing is "I want to proceed further in python execution flow"

Comment: The `SIGABRT` handler can respawn the process if that's what he wants, though that's not how I interpreted "proceed further".  I assumed that meant within the same process, so the best one can do is proceed to enter a debugger or do logging/cleanup, because the process is doomed once the `SIGABRT` handler returns.

Comment: import signal, os
import time

def handler(signum, frame):
    print "Signal!"
 signal.signal(signal.SIGABRT, handler)

Comment: @eryksun ,@ Chris Beck import signal, os import time def handler(signum, frame): print "Signal!" signal.signal(signal.SIGABRT, handler) is this what all I have to do?